# What limits scalability of a multi-threaded application that uses Python C-API?

Tags: python, c, multithreading

I have an application written in C that is multi-threaded and uses the Python C-API on a single Python interpreter. Each process receives data, converts it to PyObjects, runs a Python function and converts the results back to C types like this Pseudocode:

```
run_py_function(data) {
    PyGILState_STATE gstate;
    gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

    /* Run C -> PyObject conversions */
    PyObject *pArgs = ...


    /* Call the Python function */
    PyObject *pRet = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);

    /* Do output conversions */
    ret = ...

    PyGILState_Release(gstate);
    return ret;
}
```

This function is called by multiple threads. With this multi-threading I do not expect a speedup due to the GIL (it is more like a requirement of the surrounding code), however I expect performance similar to single-threaded execution.

This is indeed the case on one machine, but certainly not on a different one, where execution is significantly slower independent from the number of threads (but >1). I introduced some thread-local profiling around the steps of the basic function, including waiting for the GIL, input conversion, execution and output conversion. Runtimes are accumulated over all function calls. Results are as follows:

**Machine 1, single-threaded:**

Thread 0: Wait: 0.000347s        Incon: 0.088142s        Exec: 2.729928s         Outcon: 0.040163s

**Machine 1, multi-threaded:**

Thread 0: Wait: 0.175036s        Incon: 0.025976s        Exec: 0.715943s         Outcon: 0.011034s
(remaining 3 threads similar)

**Machine 2, single-threaded:**

Thread 0: Wait: 0.002864s    Incon: 0.120592s    Exec: 4.243616s     Outcon: 0.051625s

**Machine 2, multi-threaded:**

Thread 0: Wait: 0.016123s    Incon: 0.115358s    Exec: 3.010255s     Outcon: 0.043184s
(remaining 3 threads similar)

The machines have enough physical cores. Machine 1 runs Python 3.6.9, Machine 2 runs 3.6.12, but I do not see any significant changes except security fixes between the versions. Load is evenly distributed between the threads. On machine 1, every thread of the 4 running threads has 1/4 of the runtime. As the threads run sequentially due to the GIL, runtime is nearly equal to single-threaded runtime. However, on machine 2, every thread has significantly more runtime than 1/4 of the single-threaded runtime, which leads to a significantly larger overall runtime.

**Question**: What might limit the scalability here?

I initially thought that Python might perform thread switching here and saving/reloading thread states might be a problem, but setting the switch interval in the Python function did not help. Additionally I tried locking a mutex before aquiring the GIL and releasing after releasing the GIL to ensure that threads are not switched, but that didn't help either.

Comment: if the mutex requires a context switch that's going to be very costly. It can be that the other thread has been chosen to run in another core is doing something *else*

Comment: I think your only way forward is to make some debug printouts per thread, with timers, to see in which code sections it spends most time (waiting) or runs slower than expected.

Comment: @SvenNilsson That's what the runtimes mentioned above indicate. The "Exec" time represents the time spent in the "PyObject_CallObject" call per thread. All threads have similar (slow) runtimes.